# Creating DApps over existing crypto

Tags: dapps

Can I create DApps over existing crypto in the network, if yes then please help me with some like or description of the process to create such DApps if anyone can point me some blog then it will be very good.

Comment: Can you add more details? Like what type of dapp you want to create and what crypto is your target?

Comment: It's like I have launched my token over ethereum and later allow others to build dapps over that.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. You only need the contract's ABI to interact with it from a Dapp. The description of your problem is very generic, any Dapp implements that type of functionality, decentralized exchanges, gambling platforms, prediction markets, etc.